# program wont list second metod (Vypocetrychlosti2)

Tags: c#

I need to do in the main program, the user enters the measured speed of the car in the village. You will then use this speed as a parameter when calling the following methods. Define the following methods:
· The first method will return whether the measured speed exceeded the maximum allowed speed in the village, ie 50 kilometers per hour

· The second method will return nothing. It will list.
If you exceed a speed of less than 20 km / h in the village "uložení blokové pokuty do 1 000 Kč a současně udělením dvou trestných bodů"
If you exceed the maximum allowed speed in the village by 20 km / h and more "uložení blokové pokuty do 2500 Kč za současného připsání tří bodů"
Exceeding the maximum allowed speed in the village by 40 km / h and more "nelze řešit na místě uložením blokové pokuty, ale případ je ihned předáván do správního řízení. (Přestupci pak hrozí jednak pokuta od pěti do deseti tisíc korun, pět bodů  a zákaz činnosti na 6 měsíců až 1 rok.)"

My question is why program wont list second method (Vypocetrychlosti2)?? Nothin will show up..

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Zadej naměřenou rychlost v obci");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Vypocetrychlosti(input);
            Vypocetrychlosti2(input);
        }
        static double Vypocetrychlosti(int rychlost)
        {
            if (rychlost<50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Jel jsi podle předpisů");
            }
            else if (rychlost>50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nejel jsi podle předpisů, dostaneš pokutu");
            }
            else if (rychlost == 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Jel jsi jen tak tak");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Chyba");
            }
            return rychlost;
        }   
        public static void Vypocetrychlosti2 (int rychlost)
        {
            if (rychlost>50 & rychlost >70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Uložení blokové pokuty do 1 000 Kč a současně udělením dvou trestných bodů.");
            }
            else if (rychlost> 70 & rychlost<90 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("uložení blokové pokuty do 2500 Kč za současného připsání tří bodů");
            }
            else if (rychlost>90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("nelze řešit na místě uložením blokové pokuty, ale případ je ihned předáván do správního řízení. (Přestupci pak hrozí jednak pokuta od pěti do deseti tisíc korun, pět bodů  a zákaz činnosti na 6 měsíců až 1 rok.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What value did you input?

Comment: The value I input was 60

Comment: @KlausGütter got it thank you for notice me!

Comment: Then it's clear: none of the if-conditions in `Vypocetrychlosti2` are true. The first one looks strange, probably you meant `rychlost>50 & rychlost <=70`, or?